# Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds problem

Tags: mqtt, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

A month ago, I created a code and uploaded it to the NodeMCU (ESP8266) in which the NodeMCU establishes connection with the aREST.io MQTT broker. It worked properly.
The code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <aREST.h>

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

aREST rest = aREST(client);

char* key = "the api key in aREST account";
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "Pass";

#define trigger 5
#define echo 4
float distance;

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);

void setup(void)
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(trigger, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  
  rest.setKey(key);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  rest.variable("distance",&distance);

  rest.set_name("esp8266");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

}

void loop() {
rest.handle(client);

digitalWrite(trigger, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigger, LOW);

int timin = pulseIn(echo,HIGH);
distance = (171.5*((timin)))*10E-5;
delay(60);
  
  
  rest.publish(client, "distance", distance, 60000);

}
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

  rest.handle_callback(client, topic, payload, length);

}
```

At the moment, the ESP8266 can't connect to the broker. It prints the following message after it connects to WiFi on the serial monitor:
"Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds"

I checked the API key about 5 times. it's the right one
I analyzed the network with wireshark and obtained the following:

[image]

As shown in the photo, the ESP8266 sends a CONNECT data packet to the aREST broker. The broker responds with the CONNACK packet. It's repeated every 5 seconds the content in the CONNECT packet:

[image]

the content of the CONNACK:

[image]

Comment: where is `setServer`?

Comment: I added it as I troubleshoot but nothing changed

Comment: I don't think setServer is optional

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue may be that the broker is down.

Your code looks like a modified version of the 'ESP8266_cloud.ino' code found in the ArduionIDE examples. I have an ESP8266 D1 and ran that example code with my own API plugin from aREST.io and get the same error message as you.

Running example code 'mqtt_esp8266.ino' I see interaction with my board to the broker, so I don't have reason to believe there's a general hardware or connectivity issue outside of the aREST broker.

Digging into aREST.h, the MQTT broker/server is 'mqtt.arest.io'

Checking on https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mqtt.arest.io, they say it's down.

Sorry that's not more helpful :/

I tried contacting the developer/the aREST Instagram page and have yet to hear back. Will keep you posted - please update your findings as well!